# Can I add tests in custom folders under test/models related to existing models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-4

In my rails 4.2.1 app, I have a model called Foo, and the default test/models/foo_test.rb. I want to create separate tests for several different logical variants of foo, for which I would like to add a folder called test/models/foo_variants, with tests like foo_variant1_test.rb, foo_variant2_test.rb, etc.

I realize there is no model called FooVariant1, so I suspect this will not work with the convention of (modelname)_test.rb under test/models - what is the best way to enable this?

I could of course, lump all the variants' tests into foo_test.rb, but wondered if there was a more elegant way to achieve this (especially since I expect to have twenty to hundreds of variants).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using ActiveSupport::TestCase it's possible to give the test class a different name. Naming the test case differently does not mean the tests won't run.

The following should work:

test/models/foo_variants/foo_variant_1.rb

```
class FooVariant1 < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```

test/models/foo_variants/foo_variant_2.rb

```
class FooVariant2 < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  test "the truth" do
    assert true
  end
end
```